# Flask: Create content of block if it is not extended by another template

Tags: templates, flask, jinja2

I have a base template which all other templates extend:

`base.html:`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
{% block body %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Other templates will extend this template, but not completely:

`site.html:`

```
{% extends base.html %}

{% block body %}
    ...
{% endblock %}
```

The `title` block is not extended. Can I give it a default value in this case, within `base.html`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that it is sufficient to just place the content to be replaced within the block in the `base.html` file. So "extends" does not really extend (in the sense of append to) the existing content of a block, but rather replaces it.
`base.html:`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>{% block title %}Default Title{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
{% block body %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```